# Ordering of headers in Java CloseableHttpClient

Tags: java, http-headers, httpclient

I am making use of CloseableHttpClient library in java to scrape websites and depending on the website I add my own custom headers before the request is sent across to the webpage.

Although ordering of headers is not mandatory, some websites do use the header ordering as a form of fingerprinting. In CloseableHttpClient library especially, **headers such as Host, Cache-Control, Connection etc get added at the end** before the HTTP request is sent across to the destination. It looks something like this:

```
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15 646F636F6D6F3031",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "host": "www.example.com",
    "via": "1.1 localhost (squid/4.13)",
    "x-forwarded-for": "www.example.com",
    "cache-control": "max-age=259200",
    "connection": "keep-alive"
```

This is how my code works:

```
CloseableHttpClient innerClient;

HttpGet request = new HttpGet(my_url);
client.execute(request, my_context);
```

The headers are added to the HttpGet object:

```
request.addHeader("Key", "Value");
```

Irrespective of what I have tried, Host and the headers below it [as shown in the example above] get added at the end. Is there a way to control their positioning?

Comment: "some websites do use the header ordering as a form of fingerprinting" - they are doing that wrong then. and they do not follow the specification, at all. I do not think you can do that, since internally that is most probably a `Map`, that has not order at all

Comment: @Eugene what you say might be true, but many browsers, Chrome 84 as an example always maintain the same order of headers. So, certain websites use the ordering as a way to detect bots. That is precisely why I wanted to know if we would actually be able to control the ordering using HttpClient.
Also, HttpClient does allow us to order the custom headers, the only problem is with headers such as Host, Connection etc. These always get added at the end irrespective of what we do.

Comment: right, and I understand you. what I am saying that imo this is impossible to do with `CloseableHttpClient`, unless you want to override some of it's methods, if that is possible at all.

Comment: @Eugene is there is a library, Java or otherwise that allows us to control the ordering then?

Comment: I doubt it. the best way is to see if you can extend `HttpGet` and override `addHeader` may be - but that might entail many more changes, I can't be sure

Comment: Yeah, i get you. The only problem is that we are heading into dangerous territory here. It would create a lot more problem overriding the method, again if at all possible. Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to handle this with HttpClient.

If we would want to perform a round of cleanup/reordering before the request is sent out, we can make use of the **addInterceptorLast()** method as shown below.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().addInterceptorLast( 
                        new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
                            public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context){
                                // Handle the ordering here.
                            }
                        }   
                ).build();
```